# Collection validation from single validator

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-validator

Lets say that I have a class:

```
class Foo{
  @SomeCustomStringValidator
  String bar;
}
```

and then I would like to have

```
class Foo{

  List<String> bars;
}
```

Is there any way to use somehow @SomeCustomStringValidator to be applied on the `bars` collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you could use the latest Hibernate Validator 5.2 version. There is is possible to do:

```
class Foo{
  @Valid
  List<@SomeCustomStringValidator String> bars;
}
```

Otherwise you could use the class wrapping approach as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29943759/115835).

Last but not least, you could write a custom `ConstraintValidator<SomeCustomStringValidator, Collection>` and try sharing the core validation logic between this validator and the `ConstraintValidator you already have.

Comment: Sadly we don't use Java 8 yet. But I have already created custom collection validator that uses internally  SomeCustomSringValidator.

Comment: Probably the best way to go in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply wrap the class:

```
class MyString {

    @SomeCustomStringValidator
    String bar;

    // mutators
}
```

Then construct a list of `MyString`:

```
class Foo {
    List<MyString> bars;
}
```